# How to update/replace Facebook Embedded posts in html?

Tags: facebook

I want to be able to update/replace embedded facebook posts in my website.
For example say i have this code (part of the codesnippet is taken from facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts)):

```html
<html>
    <title>My Website</title>
<body>
    <button onclick="replacePost();">replace</button>
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.2"async></script>
    <div id="myDiv">
         <div class="fb-post"
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/1234"
       data-width="500"></div>
    </div>
  
    <script>
      function replacePost()
      {
        var newHTML = '<div class="fb-post"';
        newHTML += 'data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers/posts/123"';
        newHTML += 'data-width="500"></div>';
        $("#myDiv").html(newHTML);
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here as an example, when the page loads, there is a button and then the facebook post with the id 123 will pop up as expected. And when i click the button, i use jQuery to find the parent div of the facebookpost, and replace it with some new HTML. In this case, a post with the id 1234. But the post will not pop up :-( (Hopefully, you can see what i am trying to do).

So how do i dynamically delete a post and replace it with another post?

Comment: why would you want to do that? i mean, the post will not really get deleted, so why even use the embedded post plugin if you want to replace the content anyway?

Comment: It was just a simple example. I simply want to replace posts in different situations without loading a whole new HTML. So far, i am only able to show a post once, then if i want to show another post, then i have to reload the whole page, but i wanna just delete that html and set a new post in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse your html again so that the facebook sdk can fetch the new post. If you change your JavaScript to the following:

```
  <script>
      function replacePost()
      {
        var newHTML = '<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/"data-width="500">';
        $("#myDiv").html(newHTML);
        FB.XFBML.parse() //<---- add this 
      }
    </script>
```

Then each time you call replacePost you html will be parsed again. Instead of parsing the whole page you can parse a specific tag for the sake of efficiency:

```
 FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

Docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse